# C++ Concepts: exactly how strictly are the coditions in a 'require' clause enforced?

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-concepts

Here I detail a MWE of what seems to be a quirk of the `requires` clause used in a concept. What I want is a concept that indicates whether or not a certain function type is callable with a series of arguments. I realize that this is is provided by `std::invocable`, but what I have here will illustrate the point.

Consider the following concept:

```
template <typename func_t, typename... args_t>
concept callable = requires(const func_t& f, const args_t&... args) {f(args...);};
```

This is fairly straigtforward: if I have a `func_t`, can I call it with `args_t...`? By my unserstanding, the concept should evaluate to true provided that calling the function with the provided arguments is a valid operation, *including conversions*. For example, if I have a lambda:

```
auto func = [](const double& i) -> void {};
```

Then both of the following concepts evaluate to `true`:

```
callable<decltype(func), int>    //true
callable<decltype(func), double> //true
```

This is seemingly because there is a conversion from `int` to `double`. This is fine, as this is behaviour I want in the project that made me discover this issue.

Now, I would like to call my lambda with a type that is a bit more complicated, something like the following:

```
auto func = [](const type1_t<space1>& t1) -> int {return 1;};
```

Consider the following types:

```
enum space {space1,space2};

template <const space sp> struct type2_t{};

template <const space sp> struct type1_t
{
    type1_t(){}

    template <const space sp_r>
    type1_t(const type2_t<sp_r>& t2){}
};
```

Here we can convert `type2_t` to `type1_t` regardless of the template parameters, owing to the constructor template in `type1_t`. Under these conditions, the following concepts evaluate to `true`:

```
callable<decltype(func), type1_t<space1>> //true
callable<decltype(func), type2_t<space1>> //true
callable<decltype(func), type2_t<space2>> //true
```

Let's say I don't want any conversion between types that have different `space` parameters. There are a couple of ways to do this, but I will choose to use a `requires` clause on the `type1_t` constructor:

```
template <const space sp_r>
requires (sp_r == sp)
type1_t(const type2_t<sp_r>& t2)
{
    //all other code remains unchanged.
}
```

After this chance, I get the following evaluations:

```
callable<decltype(func), type1_t<space1>> //true
callable<decltype(func), type2_t<space1>> //true
callable<decltype(func), type2_t<space2>> //false
```

This is the behaviour I expect, as the code in the `requires` clase of the concept no longer compiles.

Now, let's say that I remove the `requires` clause in the constructor of `type1_t`, and that the constructor now calls a member function called `dummy_func`:

```
template <const space sp> struct type1_t
{
    type1_t(){}

    template <const space sp_r>
    void dummy_func(const type2_t<sp_r>& t2){}

    template <const space sp_r>
    type1_t(const type2_t<sp_r>& t2)
    {
        dummy_func(t2);
    }
};
```

The constructor remains virtually unchanged so the concepts all evaluate to `true` once again:

```
callable<decltype(func), type1_t<space1>> //true
callable<decltype(func), type2_t<space1>> //true
callable<decltype(func), type2_t<space2>> //true
```

The strange behaviour comes when we introduce a `requires` clause on `dummy_func`:

```
template <const space sp_r>
requires (sp_r == sp)
void dummy_func(const type2_t<sp_r>& t2){}
```

With this clause, I expect the following concept evaluations:

```
callable<decltype(func), type1_t<space1>> //true
callable<decltype(func), type2_t<space1>> //true
callable<decltype(func), type2_t<space2>> //false
```

However, when I compile with the new clause, I actually get:

```
callable<decltype(func), type1_t<space1>> //true
callable<decltype(func), type2_t<space1>> //true
callable<decltype(func), type2_t<space2>> //true
```

This is strange to me as the following will compile:

```
auto func = [](const type1_t<space1>& t1) -> int {return 1;};
func(type1_t<space1>());
```

but this will not compile:

```
func(type2_t<space2>());
```

To me, this is contradictory with the concept `callable<decltype(func), type2_t<space2>>` evaluating to `true`, as I am directly using the body of code within the `requires` clause.

What is the source of this contradiction? Why is the compiler not fully checking the validity of the code within the `requires` clause of the concept?

**Appendix**

Two disclaimers:

1. I am aware that I should be using `std::invocable`. The above is for illustration only. Note that the same problem arises when I use `std::invocable`.
2. I can fix the issue by placing the constraint on the constructor of `type1_t`, but this is undesireable in my project.

For the full code that shows the issue, please refer to the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <concepts>

enum space
{
    space1,
    space2
};

template <typename func_t, typename... args_t>
concept callable = requires(const func_t& f, const args_t&... args) {f(args...);};

template <const space sp> struct type2_t{};

template <const space sp> struct type1_t
{
    type1_t(){}

    template <const space sp_r>
    requires (sp_r == sp)
    void dummy_func(const type2_t<sp_r>& t2){}

    template <const space sp_r>
    type1_t(const type2_t<sp_r>& t2)
    {
        dummy_func(t2);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    auto func = [](const type1_t<space1>& t1) -> int {return 1;};
    std::cout << callable<decltype(func), type1_t<space1>> << std::endl; //true
    std::cout << callable<decltype(func), type2_t<space1>> << std::endl; //true
    std::cout << callable<decltype(func), type2_t<space2>> << std::endl; //true, should be false!!
}
```

Note that I am using g++ 11.3 with the `-std=c++20` flag.

Comment: The ill-formedness of `func(type2_t<space2>())` isn't in the immediate context. Evaluating the constraint doesn't instantiate the constructor template, so it never checks `dummy_func`

Comment: "I can fix the issue by placing the constraint on the constructor of type1_t, but this is undesireable in my project." `requires` in this case *should* be applied transitively. Either that or define `requires (sp_r != sp) void dummy_func` also.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Constraints on functions constrain the function *signature*; they have nothing to do with the *body* of a function. Constraints don't care if the body would fail to compile; they only care about the validity of the constraints applied to that function's signature. So if you want a function to be constrained, you *must* put those constraints in *that function's* signature.

And yes, that does recursively propagate up the call graph. That's just something you have to deal with. This is one of the reasons why bundling arbitrary expression constraints into named `concept`s is useful.